# Is more weight given to links in heading tags in terms of SEO?

Tags: seo, links, backlinks, heading

Do links in heading tags on a website give more weight than links in normal text?

Comment: Weight in terms of what?   Link juice (PageRank), anchor text, number of users that click, or something else?

Comment: I'm just curious if they have any difference in effect at all, but when I said weight, I was thinking link juice.

Comment: Made a small update in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and No. Both for weight and passed value (aka juice). It is a trick that people are using- but it really is a foolish idea if the thought is that it will advantage search engine performance. It won't in the least.

Think about it. It is an internal link- how can it pass more *juice* than any other internal link? It can't. The reason is simple- no search engine is looking for links in header tags specifically. It is just a link. Links are rated like content in relation to and distance from a header tag or title tag for value. This is primarily for semantic searches to better understand the content topic and theme. There is no boost if the link is in the header, but there is a semantic boost if it is close. There is no SEO code or metric that is advantaging a link in a header tag. None at all.

Now to caution you a bit. SEO is really not that complicated. Yes there are lots of moving parts, but it still is not so complicated that these funny little tricks really do anything. It is just a bunch of SEO blather/foolishness that gets passed along and some people try it. Stop following the small day to day parroting by bloggers and follow the core principles and you will do a lot better for yourself. It is not uncommon that 100 then 1000 bloggers latch onto something one person says and then it goes viral (actually not as viral as you may think). It is a game to stand out as an SEO expert/blogger. Most of these posts are junk or at-least over blown. Some have value of course. Learn to separate the bull from the facts and you will be much better off.

Comment: I didn't actually read that from anywhere, but I was thinking that since I know headers count for more in SEO than text when it comes to actual content, does the same apply to links.

Comment: Headers yes. Links no. There are some folks out there that put links in headers thinking that there is an SEO advantage. It is not so uncommon as you may think. But there is no difference header or not.

Comment: But you are saying that links closer to headers count for more right?

Comment: No. Only for semantic search- keywords- not link value. The original consideration is from top to bottom aka spider read order. It was once believed that the most important links were at the top of the content working downward. But that is limited too because Google realized that is actually not true. So now links within semantic keywords in content can weigh more depending upon the content and placement.